# Xcode : Is there a way to search string in expressions defined in breakpoints?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I followed this [tuto](http://www.raywenderlich.com/28289/debugging-ios-apps-in-xcode-4-5) about debugging in XCode. I got rid of some NSLog instructions in favor of expressions defined in breakpoints with an **automatic continuation**.

Ex :

```
expr (void)NSLog(@"Comments %@",data)
```

After a while, I wanted to search the breakpoint which printed a specific string.

I can't find a way to do this in XCode. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do this from the UI.  Please file an enhancement request with http://bugreporter.apple.com for some kind of "find in breakpoint commands", that seems a useful thing to do.  You can hack around this by searching for your log text in the data file that holds your user breakpoints, which is in your .xcodeproj directory in xcuserdata/.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist.  That should be considered a read-only file, I wouldn't try to edit it...

Comment: Ok then. Thank you for your answer.